# Passing a serverside variable to a javascript function in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, parameters

I need to pass a server side variable to my javascript function such as below:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkIDNum" runat="server" NavigateUrl="javascript:ChangeLocView('ChangeView', '<%#Container.DataItem("IDNum")%>')"><%#Container.DataItem("IDNum")%></asp:HyperLink>
```

I get an error at the serverside variable being passed into the Javascript function.

**Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.**

Can anyone assist?

Comment: Have you tried using Eval() isntead of Container.DataItem? This link is is some kind of databound control, right?

Comment: @James, you are correct, it is databound

Comment: don't you need an space? like `<% #Co...` and `...) %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkIDNum" 
           runat="server" 
           NavigateUrl=<%# "javascript:ChangeLoc('ChangeView', '" + Container.DataItem("IDNum") + "')" %>>
     <%#Container.DataItem("IDNum")%>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: When I use your code, I get "Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Are you sure its caused the `NavigateUrl`? Try this: `Container.DataItem("IDNum").ToString()` in the `NavigateUrl` assignment.

Comment: I do believe we have a winner !!..   Thanks @Mrchief

Answer (score 1):

You probably should set the attributes in the code behind.

```
string idNum = Container.DataItem("IDNum");
lnkIDNum.NavigateUrl = 
    "javascript:ChangeLocView ('ChangeView', '" 
  + idNum 
  + "'";
lnkIDNum.Text = idNum;
```

and in the aspx:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkIDNum" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Eval() function instead, and do something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" NavigateUrl="someFunc('ChangeView', '<%#Eval("SomeColumn")%>');"><%#Eval("SomeColumn")%></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Even with the Eval function, same message

Comment: There's something else wrong with your code then. This shouldn't produce any errors.