# How to determine which button was clicked in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and my gridview has a template feild for image button,for delete one row.
At the moment I use rowcommand and rowargument for this image button to recognize what row want to delete. but I need to implement below scenario:

I want when user click on imagebutton,no postback occured ,a modal box(bootstrap modal) open ,and only when user click yesI'm sure button in modal, postback occure and data deleted...

Is this possible with asp.net gridview and if yes,How I can determine what button click in "yesI'm sure button" ???

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Please try the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowModal(gridItemIndex) 
    {
        $(document).ready(function () 
            {
                $('#mymodal').modal('show');
                var row = gridItemIndex.parentNode.parentNode;
                var rowIndex = row.rowIndex-1; //row index of that row.
                document.getElementById("<%=hfID.ClientID %>").value =rowIndex;
            });
    }

</script>

<asp:gridview id="yourGridView" onrowcommand="GridView_RowCommand"
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton name="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return ShowModal(this);" ImageUrl="/imagepath.pgn" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:gridview>
```

Then in code behind use the following event of `GridView`.

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName=="Delete")
    {
        // Write your delete code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,but I want to use bootstrap modal,is there any way?

Comment: Yes there is a way. You can create a javascript function with bootstrap code in it. Then call this javascript function like : OnClientClick='return yourJavascriptFunction();'

Comment: ok,but how to pass gridview rowindex in modal confirm button event?

Comment: I updated my answer. <%# Container.DataItemIndex %> will give Grid item index.

Comment: It doesn't work :( . I write a javascript function and pass <%# Container.DataItemIndex %> ,but It pass this (<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>) as an string not rowindex

Comment: Try this
OnClientClick='<%#    
GetId(Container.DataItemIndex.ToString()) %>'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193464/passing-a-serverside-variable-to-a-javascript-function-in-asp-net

Comment: khalil : thank you,Finally I can get row index with your solution but with a little change in it.